# Are there any naturally sweet legumes?

Tags: sugar, beans, legumes

I'm just wondering if any legumes are sweet. Preferably, I'd like a sweet bean, but whatever works.

Comment: Can I recommend you be more specific? Melons are legumes, but I think you are looking for something more like beans.

Comment: @Escoce Legumes are members of the family Fabaceae -- peas, beans, peanuts, and some related plants. Melons are the family Cucurbitaceae. (I know this can be a potential point of confusion because in e.g. French "légume" simply means "vegetable". But in English the usage is much more restricted.)

Answer (score 1):

Peas are very sweet, especially when you eat them young. I don't think any others reach them, but I don't think I've tried every legume in the world, so it's possible.

If the natural sweetness of legumes isn't sufficient for you, they take very well to added sugar.

Answer (score 1):

[adzuki beans](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adzuki_bean) are quite sweet and used to make various desserts in Asia.

I will note, however, that typically some form of sugar is also added in whatever dish is being prepared with them.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing Wikipedia's list of [edible legumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Edible_legumes), there are in fact a lot more candidates than I expected!

**Green peas**

Young green peas (not the dried split green peas you use in soup) are relatively sweet as far as vegetables go. In particular **sugar snap peas** (i.e. mangetout) are named for their sweetness. Still not overwhelmingly sweet; their 4g of sugar / 100g is comparable to a carrot.

**Adzuki beans**

Although not particularly sweet in their own right, these beans are used to make [red bean paste](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_bean_paste), a popular ingredient in East Asian desserts. The beans are fully cooked, sometimes mashed, and often mixed with copious amounts of sugar. Other beans can be prepared in the same manner for use in sweet dishes.

**Tamarind**

I was surprised to learn tamarind is in fact a legume! Though it doesn't look like the legumes in your garden, growing as a tree reaching 25 meters in height! The fruit grow in a 12-15cm pod that does look distinctly bean-like. Anyhow, these may be the winner when it comes to saccharine concentration: with 57g of sugar / 100g, tamarind pulp is quite sweet.

***[Detarium senegalense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detarium_senegalense)***

Another leguminous tree, this one native to West Africa, is again known for its sweet fruit. I don't much about the plant, even the English Wikipedia page was pretty light, but it does appear to be used in sweet culinary applications. Maybe someone from Senegal could chime in.

**[Ice-cream bean tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inga_edulis)**

Well this one has a delicious-sounding name. Native to the South America, and known for the sweet and distinctively flavored pulpy fruit, it purportedly tastes like vanilla ice cream. If you had to pick one of these options to consume as dessert in its own right, this seems like your legume!

Answer (score -1):

Green peas, chickpeas, maybe fava beans